# having a dummy mouse on webpage

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

i have a testcase in which i want the user to have 2 mouses (1 being dummy) and whenever the user moves mouse1(original mouse) mouse2 should also move . suppose (x,y) are the coordinates of mouse1 then the coordinates of mouse2 should be (x+500px,y).I tried doing

```
const dummyMouse = document.querySelector('.dummy-mouse')
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', async event => {
        if (dummyMouse) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                const mouseTop = event.clientY
                let mouseLeft = event.clientX + 300

                dummyMouse.style.transform = `translate(${mouseLeft},${mouseTop})`
            }, 100);
        }

    })
```

where dummyMouse is pointing towards an empty div whose styling is

```
.dummy-mouse{
    position: fixed;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

but this solution is giving abnormal results like

1. sometimes it is working and sometimes it is not
2. errors like clientY not defined
3. The visibility of the dummy mouse is intermittently turning on and off

so basically the code is not working as functioned. why is that ? and what is the solution or alternative for this

[image: the webpage]

this is the webpage comparing data of two different users where i need the dummy mouse

Comment: I’m not sure that the setTimeout is necessary, what happens if you remove it so that dummyMouse.style.transform is set directly within the mouse move listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `setTimeout` call and don't mark your event handlers as `async`. Oh, and don't forget that `style.transform` expects *a unit*, not mere numbers. See:

```js
const dummyMouse = document.querySelector('.dummy-mouse');
if (dummyMouse) { // <-- moved the if outside, no need for an event listener if the element is not available
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', event => {
    const mouseTop = event.clientY
    const mouseLeft = event.clientX + 300
    dummyMouse.style.transform = `translate(${mouseLeft}px,${mouseTop}px)`; // <-- added px
  });
}
```

```css
.dummy-mouse{
    position: fixed;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="dummy-mouse"></div>
```